# Transferring photos from Windows 7 to iPod

Tags: windows-7, ipod

What folder on the iPod can I move photos into using Windows 7?

Comment: Use iTunes and do a photo sync.

Answer (score 2):

Within itunes you can specify a folder to sync, when you are in the settings for the iPod.

Pick a folder and put your photos in there.

Personally, I have an 'iPod Photos' folder on my desktop, and sync that. Then I can put any photos I want to sync into that folder.

Cheers